# Gantt Chart in R

Tags: r, scheduling, gantt-chart

I want to plot a scheduling diagram, in other words, Gantt Chart, in R.

What I have is a two dimensional array. A sample array is attache below.

```
:     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    :=
1    1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2    0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
3    0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
4    0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
5    1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
6    1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
7    1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
8    1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
9    0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
10   1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0 
11   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
12   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
13   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
14   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
15   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
16   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
17   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
18   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
19   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
20   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
21   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
22   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
23   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
24   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   0.0
25   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   1.0
26   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0
27   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0
28   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   1.0
29   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   1.0
30   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0
31   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0
32   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   1.0
33   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0
34   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0
35   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0
36   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0
```

Each row denotes a time period, and each column denotes a project. If the number in the cell is 1, it means the current project is scheduled to run during this time period. There are 12 projects and 36 months. Is there any way to draw the gantt chart efficiently?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is `?plotrix::gantt.chart` what you are looking for?

Comment: I am not sure how to apply this function to the binary matrix like this.

Answer (score 1):

Well as a starter, here's a quick & dirty approach using ggplot:

```
gantt_ <- as.data.frame(t(gantt))
df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(seq_along(gantt_), function(x) {
  r <- rle(gantt_[[x]])
  start <- cumsum(r$lengths) - r$lengths + 1
  end <- start + r$lengths - 1
  cbind(project = x, xmin = start[r$values == 1], xmax = end[r$values == 1])
}))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(transform(df, 
                 project = factor(project, levels = 36:1),
                 xmin = xmin - .1,
                 xmax = xmax + .1), 
       aes(x = xmin, xend = xmax, y = project, yend = project)) + 
  geom_segment(size = 4) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12) + labs(x = "time")
```

[image]

Data used:

```
gantt <- read.table(header=T, text="
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12
1    1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2    0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
3    0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
4    0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
5    1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
6    1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
7    1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
8    1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
9    0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
10   1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0 
11   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
12   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
13   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
14   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
15   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
16   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
17   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
18   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
19   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
20   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
21   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
22   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
23   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
24   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   0.0
25   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   1.0
26   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0
27   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0
28   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   1.0
29   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   1.0
30   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0
31   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0
32   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   1.0
33   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0
34   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0
35   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0
36   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0")
```

For more options, have a look at

```
library(sos)
findFn("gantt")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the following post. This uses ggplot as well.

https://dwh-businessintelligence.blogspot.nl/2016/05/what-if-for-project-management.html

[image: gantt ggplot]

What it basically does is draw the rectangles:

```
ggplot(dsg, aes(xmin = MinWeek, xmax = MaxWeek, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymin + 80 * (Hours/28), fill = factor(Person))) +
geom_rect() + 
facet_grid(Grouping~., scales = "free_y") + 
xlab("Week") +
theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8)) +
geom_text(aes(label = paste(Project, " (",Person, ", hrs:",Hours, ") WK:", MaxWeek , sep=""),  y = ymin + 24, x = MaxWeek - 2), size = 5) + 
geom_rect(data=dsg2, alpha=0.2) +
kobe_theme() + 
xlim(0,max(dsg[["MaxWeek"]]) + 2) +
geom_text(aes(label = Grouping,  y = 80, x = mw, size=20));
```

All the code is on github: https://github.com/stevedep/WhatIf

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12402086)

Comment: I hope this is better.